# Opening a PDF file in a PowerBuilder window

Tags: pdf, powerbuilder

Is it possible to open a PDF document in full screen mode in a powerbuilder version 2019 R3 build 2703 window?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the new webbrowser control. Send the url/path to the .pdf you want to open.  Check out the help file for more information.